# How to set a CustomScrollPanel to height 100%?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt

I want to set a [CustomScrollPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomScrollPanel.html) to height 100%; What I tried is to get the CustomScrollPanel to height 100% but it does not work that way. Here is want I tried.

```
public class MyScrollPanel extends Composite implements HasWidgets {

private ResizeLayoutPanel resizeLayoutPanel;
private CustomScrollPanel customScrollPanel;


public MyScrollPanel() {
    resizeLayoutPanel = new ResizeLayoutPanel();
    resizeLayoutPanel.setStyleName(resources.css().resizeLayoutPanel());
    customScrollPanel = new CustomScrollPanel();
    customScrollPanel.addStyleName(resources.css().customScrollPanel());


    resizeLayoutPanel.add(customScrollPanel);
    initWidget(resizeLayoutPanel);
}
```

My css:

```
.resizeLayoutPanel {
   height: 100%;
   background-color: yellow;    
}
```

**How do I get the CustomScrollPanel to height 100%?**

Comment: Did you add this to RootLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` will not work unless the parent div has a fixed height like `height:500px`.

The best way would be to calculate the height of the window / parent container and the assigning that to your div element, with a resize condition at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollPanel implements RequiresResize, which means it gets its size from its parent widget, as long as the parent widget implements ProvidesResize. If the parent widget takes 100% of the space, vertically, then the ScrollPanel will take the same space too.